# Download multiple files at once using Webclient

Tags: c#

I'm trying to download multiple files. But I can only download single file.
could someone tell how I can download multiple files using webclient?

Here's my code.

```
 async Task DownloadFile()
    {
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);

            string[] sp = Regex.Split(textBox_Result.Text, "----------", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"(https.+)[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]+[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]");

            foreach (string text in sp)
            {
                string names = text.Trim().Split(new char[]{'\n'})[0].Trim();

                foreach (object obj in regex.Matches(text))
                {
                    Match match = (Match)obj;

                    await Task.Run(() => wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(match.Value), string.Concat(new string[]
                    { txtSubOutput.Text, "\\", PARSER.GetValidFileName(names.Trim(), "."), ".m3u8" })));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are downloading multiple files as I see from you example. m3u8 file is just a bunch of plain text references, open it and download it's subparts.

Comment: It would seem to boil down to A) how many times `wc.DownloadFileAsync()` is called, and B) with what parameters for the remote URI and local path.  Only you know the values of `textBox_Result.Text` and `txtSubOutput.Text` or what `PARSER.GetValidFileName()` does, so that will be hard for anyone but you to answer.  Also, that regex, which I assume is for extracting URLs, matches text like `"httpsxyz!!!DoesThisLookValidToYou?"`.  "I can only download single file" isn't a very clear description of the result of running this code, either.

Comment: Protip: According to the documentation WebClient is obsolete for 10 years now and should not be used anymore. Use HttpClient instead.